Maximum degree of polynomial to verify its reducibility
Given a field $\mathbb{Z}_p$ with $p$ prime, I want to find a polynomial $f(x)$ that serves as modulo for $\mathbb{F}_q$ with
$$
q = p^{\deg(f(x))}. 
$$
So, as it must be irreducible, I can use a brute force approach to verify its reducibility like the following:
$$
f(x) = a_0\cdot x^{d} + a_1\cdot x^{d-1} + \cdots + a_{d},
\quad 
a_i \in \mathbb{Z}_p \quad\forall i \in [0,d]
$$
and
$$
q(x) \not\mid f(x) 
\quad \forall q(x) \in \mathbb{F}_q - \{0,1\}.
$$
However, this implies verifying the divisibility of $f(x)$ for all polynomials of $\mathbb{F}_q$ with its degree ranging from $0$ to $\deg(f(x)) - 1$.
So, is it a sufficient condition to check the divisibility with all polynomials $q(x)$ such that
$$
\deg(g(x)) \leq \biggl\lfloor \frac{\deg(f(x))}{2}
\biggr\rfloor
$$
for $f(x)$ to be irreducible?

If $f=gh$, then $\deg(g)+\deg(h)=\deg(f)$, so at least one of $g$ and $h$ must have degree greater than or equal to $\deg(f)/2$. This is the exact analogue of only needing to check divisors up to $\sqrt{n}$ to test whether $n$ itself is prime.

Your conjecture seems promising. What do you know about how the degree function interacts with multiplication of (nonzero) polynomials?

D'oh, like @ArturoMagidin said. :-)

what does "serves as modulo" mean?

@will-jagy I mean $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(f(x))$

There is a faster way to check irreducibility. But, yeah, like Arturo said, you only need to go up degree $\lfloor d/2\rfloor$. And you can assume that the leading coefficieint is equal to $1$.  Your notation is a bit off. You want to check for divisibility in the ring $\Bbb{F}_p[x]$. In the field $\Bbb{F}_q$ everything is divisible by everything non-zero. It wouldn't be a field otherwise.
